# How should I replace this jerry-rigged Trap?

Tags: plumbing, sink, p-trap

The downstairs bathroom vanity in my 60s era house leaks, I am going to replace the entire vanity. This should be quite straightforward with the exception of the P Trap (pictured).

The P Trap looks hacked together. All the online tutorials I can find for replacing a P Trap assume modern connections/threads which aren't present here. What tools/hardware do I need to pick up?

[image: P Trap 1]
[image: P Trap 2]

Comment: Sometimes the idea of if it is not broken don't fix comes in handy.  Would need to remove that P-trap to see what you have to work with, but might find that P-trap is the best solution, unless tearing out walls is something in your plans.

Comment: It would help if you could pull it apart and show us what that pipe coming out of the wall looks like, and it's diameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you think this is jury-rigged, you're new at DIYing. This is actually a pretty common fix for what looks like a 1-1/4" old chrome stub, chrome trap and brass tail pipe. The stub out of the wall has the nut for a trap. The chrome trap probably rusted away and the owner replaced it with a rubber trap with hose clamps. You might be able to replace that trap with a PVC one and use the existing nut on the drain stub out and the compression nut on the trap to the tail pipe. I'd be looking to replace that drain stub pipe. Move that collar out of the way and see it that pipe has a nut to loosen it or if it's sweated in place. If you can remove it, replace it with a   PVC one.